# Generating a random number outside of the oncreate method

Tags: android, methods, random, static

I'm trying to set up my activity so that I can generate a set of random numbers from methods outside of my onCreate method. Here's how my activity is set up...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.optionOne();
  this.optionTwo();
  this.optionThree();
}

public void optionOne() {
  // generate a random number here
  int random = Math.random();

  // generate more random numbers and do more stuff here
}
```

The problem is, any random numbers I generate outside of the onCreate method are considered 'static' and the numbers are always 0. If I generate numbers inside the onCreate method, it of course works just fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Math.random() returns 0.0 to 1.0, if you call it a 'int' it will drop the decimals leaving it to be 0.

Comment: @wtsang02 - actually I was doing Math.random(max_value), I just removed my extra numbers to simplify the example. Although, your other answer solved my problem! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Random ranGenerator=new Random();
```

Declare it as a member of the class.
then just call `ranGenerator.nextInt()` any time to get it.

Comment: Thank you! You spared me one big headache.

Answer (score 1):

To generate random number use,this will create random between specific range

```
public void optionOne() {
   var=(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)    //math.random will return integer values 
  // use your var wisely
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int random = rand.nextInt();
```

or

```
int random = rand.nextInt(range);
```

According to doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

```
Math.random() Returns a pseudo-random double n, where n >= 0.0 && n < 1.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to create an array list of non repeating random numbers

```
 ArrayList<Integer> indexArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (i = 0; i < 202; ++i) {
                number.add(i);
                // number.add(num);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(number);
```